# Wrapping PreferredSize with Obx

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

```
class BottomOfAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {

  BottomOfAppBar({Key? key, required this.tabs}) : super(key: key);
  final List<Widget> tabs;
  final tabbarenable2 = Get.find<RxBool>(tag: 'tabbarenable');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() => Container(
          child: ColoredBox(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                tabbarenable2.value
                    ? TabBar(
                        labelColor: Colors.purple[100],
                        indicatorColor: Colors.purple,
                        isScrollable: true,
                        labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                        tabs: tabs)
                    : Text(tabbarenable2.value.toString())
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => tabbarenable2.value
      ? const Size.fromHeight(28.0)
      : const Size.fromHeight(0.0);
}
```

for AppBar bottom properties I am calling BottomOfAppBar class for state management. If tabbarenable tag true run the first conditions and vice versa.

The main problem is I cannot get wrap the preferredSize and I cannot apply the latest state for it.

What kind of approach can I use for it? `Obx` does not work with preferredSize but when I remove the TabBar I have to assign value to `preferredSize` as (0,0)

Comment: did you try to assign these sizes to your container? that should work with the same result of preferredSize

Comment: bottom: is a properties of AppBar, there is no any contain

Comment: You can't wrap appBar in Obx, as it is not a subtype of PreferredSizeWidget. Try wrapping only the stateful data with Obx (while passing value to attributes of Appbar or its children)